# Magento how to manually update payment Success information in Order page

Tags: magento

Am using ccavenue for accepting payments with my Magento cart. After payment was accepted at CCAvenue there was a WARNING which prevented SUCCESS data to be sent to Magento store. This resulted in Order NOT SHOWING the payment received. How can i manually edit payment data in Order page to appropriately show amount received and thus actually show it in Sales/Revenue also??

Comment: I would also like to know how I can do this.  In my case, it's authorize.net that's not properly updating payment information on certain product types.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented above, my issue was similar, but with authorize.net.  I was seeking to manually change the status of the order because I was not able to retrieve payment updates in certain situations (suspected fraud).

Solved by changing the following:

1. Making certain that api updates were enabled in authorize.net settings.
2. Changing the url inside /app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php to represent the NON-testing version.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=12991

For some inscrutable reason, this bug was reported for 1.5 and remains in 1.7, so perhaps your issue has a similar solution or workaround to get payment information to fetch.